# Not able to install OPAM packages

Tags: ocaml, opam

I'm supposed to put these commands in my Ubuntu terminal to download OPAM packages.

```
opam install -y utop odoc ounit2 qcheck bisect_ppx menhir ocaml-lsp-server ocamlformat ocamlformat-rpc
```

But I'm getting this error upon entering the commands.

```
Fatal error:
In /home/(my username)/.opam/cs3110-2022fa/.opam-switch/packages/astring.0.8.5/opam:
unsupported or missing file format version
```

The same error also occurs when I use almost any command starting with opam.

Comment: Please edit to include text as text rather than linking to or inlining images.

Comment: What is your `opam`version?

Comment: The opam version is 2.0.5

Comment: How did you install opam?

Comment: by putting the command: sudo apt install opam                                                                  And then: opam init --bare -a -y   (to initialize it)

Comment: There may be a bug in the package. Perhaps try installing opam by following these instructions: https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html

Comment: I would never recommend from my experience to install opam or OCaml from a package manager. Instead, install via the install script @Chris mentions. Then install OCaml via an Opam switch.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems likely to be a bug in the OP's Linux distribution's package for opam or OCaml. The answer likely lies with following the instructions [here](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Install.html) to install opam, and then install OCaml via an opam switch.

At this time, opam can be installed with the following command.

```bash
bash -c "sh <(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)"
```